# Combine/merge results from two queries from different databases

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, php

I am trying to produce a web report using PHP that takes a query from a SQL Server database for the main query, and another query from a PostgreSQL database.

What is the best way to merge the results? Currently I am outputting the results as arrays.

The two arrays are made up like so:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [site_name] => TESTSITE
            [status] => 1
        )
)
```

```
Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [site_name] => TESTSITE
            [booking_id] => 2156
            [jobresults_key] => 1239
            [result] => 4
        )
)
```

The common items are `[site_name]` in both arrays, and I want to display the `[status]` from array1 if there is nothing for the matching `[site_name]` in array2, if there is a matching `[site_name]` in array2 then it should display `[result]`.

Comment: Will arrays always be the same length? Or do you have to check through all items between both?

Comment: array1 will always be larger then array2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the arrays are short and array1 is always larger, this should work fine.

```
$array1 = array(
    array(
        'site_name' => 'TESTSITE',
        'status' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'site_name' => 'TESTSITE-2',
        'status' => 1
    )
);
$array2 = array(
    array(
        'site_name' => 'TESTSITE',
        'booking_id' => 2156,
        'jobresults_key' => 1239,
        'result' => 4
    )
);
foreach($array1 as &$item1){
    foreach($array2 as $item2){
        if( $item1['site_name'] === $item2['site_name'] ){
            $item1 = array_replace($item1, $item2);
        }
    }
}
print_r($array1);
```

Comment: Thanks Ill give that a go.